# ArcGIS Select Analysis using Unique Values from Field

Tags: python, arcpy, sql

I am trying to create separate shapefile using Select analysis with ArcPy by doing an SQL query to create them based on a unique value from the field. I want to create a list of the unique values in the table from a specific field since there are some duplicates of the same value in the field. I want to do a search of the table and find all the unique values and then append them to the list and then do the Select analysis to create individual shapefiles and eventually individual KML files. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Do you have any basic code? It is much easier to assist if we have some starting point to use as reference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Split Layers by Attributes](http://resources.arcgis.com/gallery/file/geoprocessing/details?entryID=37AEB018-1422-2418-A036-CA6D9920F808) will allow you to get individual shapefiles using a query.  Inputs are a shapefile, the destination is a folder for the output shapefiles to go.  You can parse the code if you have some means to create kml files directly, otherwise, explore various options on the ESRI geoprocessing website.

Comment: Thank you so much. This tool helped out alot. I wish it was integrated into ArcPy as a standard feature especially given Select Analysis.